# gallery filter with several pics per category

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, gallery

i have the following problem;
I made a gallery with a filter, but if I click on Mobile, for example, then only one picture shows, although there are many pictures in Categories mobile.
So when I click on a category I want to show all the pictures in this category

Here is the code

Hello,
i have the following problem;
I made a gallery with a filter, but if I click on Mobile, for example, then only one picture shows, although there are many pictures in Categories mobile.
So when I click on a category I want to show all the pictures in this category

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
    body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p{
    outline: 2px solid red;
    padding-inline-start: 20px; 
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
section{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
section ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;

}
section ul .liste{
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}
/* خدعة عمل كلاس  */
ul .liste.active,
ul .liste:hover{
    background-color: #7C0501;
    color: #fff;

}

.product{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media (max-width:700px) {
    
.product{
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


}
/* خدعة الصور */
.product .itemBox{
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}

.product .itemBox img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>MUHAMMAD</p>
    <section>
        <ul>
            <li class="liste active" data-filter="All">All</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter=".mobile"> Mobile</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter=".camera"> Camera</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter=".watch"> Uhren</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter=".shoes"> Schuhe</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter=".headphone"> Headphone </li>


        </ul>

<div class="product">
    <div class="itemBox mobile ">   <img src="pics/mobile1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile5.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox watch">   <img src="pics/watch1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox watch">   <img src="pics/watch2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox watch">   <img src="pics/watch3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox watch">   <img src="/pics/watch4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox camera">   <img src="/pics/camera1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox headphone">   <img src="/pics/headphone1.jpg" alt=""></div>



</div>







    </section>
    


    <script>
let filtern=document.querySelectorAll(".liste");
let filterArray=Array.from(filtern);
let divs=document.querySelectorAll(".product>div");
let divArray=Array.from(divs);

for(i=0; i<filterArray.length;i++){

    filterArray[i].addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
               let clicko=e.currentTarget;
            for(i=0; i<filterArray.length;i++){
                filterArray[i].classList.remove("active")
                clicko.classList.add("active")

            }

            for(let i =0;i<divArray.length; i++){
                divArray[i].style.display="none"
             }
                      /////////       هسا عملية الربط بين الكلاسات بالمحتوى و الايديات تبع التابات    ////////////
                      // dataset بتجبلك المعلومات التابعة للديف يلي له علاقة بالتارغت 
             document.querySelector(clicko.dataset.filter).style.display="block"
       

    })
}


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution;
Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution
Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution
Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution;
Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution
Thank you guys, I was able to find the solution

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    p{
        outline: 2px solid red;
        padding-inline-start: 20px; 
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    }
    section{
        padding: 20px;
        width: 1280px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    
    }
    section ul{
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    
    }
    section ul .liste{
        padding: 10px 30px;
        background-color: #eee;
        margin: 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        user-select: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    
    }
    /* خدعة عمل كلاس  */
    ul .liste.active,
    ul .liste:hover{
        background-color: #7C0501;
        color: #fff;
    
    }
    
    .product{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    @media (max-width:700px) {
        
    .product{
        display: block;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .product .itemBox.hide{
    display: none;

}
    
    }
    /* خدعة الصور */
    .product .itemBox{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    }
    
    .product .itemBox img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <ul>
            <li class="liste active" data-filter="all">All</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter="mobile"> Mobile</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter="camera"> Camera</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter="watch"> Uhren</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter="shoes"> Schuhe</li>
            <li class="liste" data-filter="headphone"> Headphone </li>


        </ul>

<div class="product">
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="mobile">   <img src="pics/mobile5.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="shoes">   <img src="pics/shoe4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="watch">   <img src="pics/watch1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="watch">   <img src="pics/watch2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="watch">   <img src="pics/watch3.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="watch">   <img src="/pics/watch4.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="camera">   <img src="/pics/camera1.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="itemBox" data-item="headphone">   <img src="/pics/headphone1.jpg" alt=""></div>



</div>







    </section>
    
    
    
        <script>
let liste=document.querySelectorAll(".liste");
let itemBox=document.querySelectorAll(".itemBox");
for(let i=0; liste.length;i++){
    liste[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(let j=0; j<liste.length;j++){
            liste[j].classList.remove("active")
        }
    this.classList.add("active")
   

    //الزيس هون بنقدر نستبدلها بباراميتر  و هون عبنقله جبلنا معلومات الداتا فيلتر يلي نقرت عليها 
    let dataFilter=this.getAttribute("data-filter"); 
                                    for(let k=0;k<itemBox.length;k++){
                                        itemBox[k].classList.remove("active");
                                        itemBox[k].classList.add("hide");

                                        if(itemBox[k].getAttribute("data-item")==dataFilter || dataFilter=="all"){
                                            itemBox[k].classList.remove("hide");
                                            itemBox[k].classList.add("active");

                                        }
                                    }
                                })

}


        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```